# How to download this Nokia developer repository

Tags: svn, nokia

How to download that repository:
http://projects.developer.nokia.com/DSP/browser/examples/WindowsPhone/NoiseReduction#sdkMicrophoneCS
I installed SVN client, getting access forbidden even tough I have Nokia Developer account. Can anybody download it for me and paste it in speedyShare?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: `svn co http://projects.developer.nokia.com/svn/DSP`.

I clicked on the link you gave and it showed this Subversion URL on that page. About the fifth line down on the Webpage. It's sort of tiny print, so it's easy to miss.

Comment: I have seen that it asks for user and password, I gave it but it said forbidden access...  but this is public repository. If you are able to download it please rar it/zip it and put on speedyshare, it will be really really helpfull.

Comment: I just did a checkout with no password. I even copied and pasted the command to my command line. Note this is `http://` and not `https://`. You can select one or the other. You can download it from my [Dropbox](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/433257/nokia-DSP.tar.gz).